# Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) lookup for latest record

Tags: pentaho, lookup

Say my lookup table looks something like

```
         Table_1
Key Id  incremental _count  date
1   1   1                   2015-05-20
2   1   2                   2015-05-20
3   1   4                   2015-05-22
4   2   1                   2015-05-22
5   1   6                   2015-05-22
```

For each Id how do I limit PDI lookup to return only the most recent record?

**OUTPUT**

```
Key Id  incremental _count  date
4   2   1                   2015-05-22
5   1   6                   2015-05-22
```

Comment: I think to answer the question we need to know more information. What type of input is your lookup table? When you say PDI lookup, to which specific PDI lookup step are you referring? Are you looking for a suggestion on which step type to use?

Answer (score 0):

it should work with this transformation  setup:

[image: My setup]

**1) Sort Rows Step:** 
       sort by (ascending): Id -> Inc -> Date

**2) 1. Group by Step:**

- *Group field*:

  - 1. date
  - 2. id
- *Aggregates:*

  - Subject: key - Type: last value
  - Subject: inc -Type:last value

**3) 2. Group by Step:**

- *Group field:*

  - 1: id
- *Aggregates:*

  - Subject: date - Type: last value
  - Subject: key - Type: last value
  - Subject: inc - Type: last value

Hope this will help.
With best regards,
S.R.

Answer (score 0):

Did similar thing - Group By over Group By with aggregate as Last Value
Thanks S.R

[image]